# Using more than two "y" axes with pylab.twinx()

Tags: matplotlib

I am plotting three different lines in the same figure using matplotlib in pylab. I want to plot a "y" axis on the right, and two on the left. Now I can plot one on the right and one on the left:

```
pylab.subplot(311)
pylab.annotate('(a)', xy=(0.03, 1e17), xycoords='data', color='k')

pylab.grid(True)
noxticks()
pylab.semilogy(t[:], pht[:])
pylab.ylabel('Total photons')

pylab.twinx()
pylab.semilogy(t[:], pht2[:])
pylab.ylabel('Received photons 1')
```

I want to add another y axis on the left to plot also pht3, but I cannot. How could I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: See this example. http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_parasite_axes2.html

Comment: Thank you. I saw this example, but I do not know how to apply it in my case using pylab. ...

Comment: pylab is just an bulk-imported namespace that pulls in `pyplot` and `numpy`, `pyplot` is just a statefull interface (designed to mimic MATLAB) wrapped around the OO interface ex: `pylab.twinx` -> `pyplot.twinx` -> `pyplot.gca().twinx` -> `ax.twinx()`.

Comment: Thank you tcaswell, I have learned how to use it.